# How to set priority of test cases in RIDE

Tags: robotframework

I have test cases in a test suite like below example:

```
MyTestSuite:

TC_01:
     Log to console **This should execute last** 

TC_02:
     Log to console **This should execute first**

TC_03:
     Log to console **This should execute second**
```

I have tried adding the ordering for the test cases like below :

```
01__TC_01:
     Log to console **This should execute last** 

02__TC_02:
     Log to console **This should execute first**

03__TC_03:
     Log to console **This should execute second**
```

I referred the below site:

https://seleniummaster.com/sitecontent/index.php/selenium-robot-framework-menu/selenium-robot-framework-python-menu/222-run-tests-in-certain-order-in-robot-framework-python

But still they run in the same order in which they are written.

Please guide me through this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Robot test cases will run in the order they appear in the file. Using names only affects the order that files within a folder are run. The only exception is if you use the [--randomize](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#randomizing-execution-order) option.

The [robot framework user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#execution-order) says this:

> Test cases in a test suite are executed in the same order as they are defined in the test case file.

For more information see the section [Test Execution](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-execution) in the robot framework user guide.